# Как искать людей по имени и фамилии в Одноклассниках через API?

Tags: javascript, парсер, api, rest, odnoklassniki-api

Я посмотрел документацию по **REST API** от Одноклассников и там нету метода для поиска людей, по имени, фамилии и другим параметрам. Есть только `users.getCurrentUser()` и `users.getInfo()`. Но ни первый ни второй метод не делают того, что я хочу